# Struggling to add has_many through relationship

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to make a has_many through relationship like this:

```
#user.rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_many :availabilities
  has_many :timeslots, :through => availabilities
end

#availability.rb
class Availability < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :timeslot
    belongs_to :user
end

#timeslot.rb
class Timeslot < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :availabilities
    has_many :timeslots, :through => availabilities
end
```

I created the two models and than ran `rake db:migrate` without adding the code in the models (to create the tables). 
I made a migration file:

```
class AddFieldsToTables < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    add_column :users, :availability_id, :integer
    add_column :timeslots, :availability_id, :integer
    add_column :availabilities, :user_id, :integer
    add_column :availabilities, :timeslot_id, :integer
  end
end
```

and ran `rake db:migrate`
Than I added the code above to all the files.
And then if I try to generate anything it gives me `NameError: undefined local variable or method availabilities for User (call 'User.connection' to establish a connection):Class`

I am new to Ruby on Rails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One issue I see is that in your `timeslot.rb` you have `has_many :timeslots, :through => availabilities`. I'm guessing you want `has_many :users, :through => :availabilites`.

Another is in `user.rb`, you have `has_many :timeslots, :through => availabilities` but you need the symbol `:availabilites`. This is what is causing the error you posted, I believe. It should look like this (all I've changed is the second-to-last line):

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_many :availabilities
  has_many :timeslots, :through => :availabilities
end
```

Comment: Isn't availabilties the plural of availablity.

Comment: Try this is in `user.rb` and you'll see what I mean: `has_many :timeslots, :through => :availabilities`

Comment: Sorry I thought you meant the plural of  availabilty is availabilties. I see what you mean now.

Answer (score 1):

I see a tiny problem in your code:

```
#timeslot.rb
class Timeslot < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :availabilities
    has_many :timeslots, :through => availabilities
end
```

it should be:

```
#timeslot.rb
class Timeslot < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :availabilities
    has_many :users, :through => availabilities
end
```

I'm not sure if it can solve your problem but your code (exclude the above mistake) sounds fine for me.

Comment: oops copy paste problem. Though I still get the error. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I see another problem here: you should use `availabilities` as a symbol (`:availabilities`) both in `user.rb` and `timeslot.rb`. It should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In order to setup `has_many through` relationship between two tables `users` and `timeslots`, you need to setup join table `availabilities` with columns `user_id` and `timeslot_id`.

Setup your rails models like below:

```
# models/user.rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :availabilities
  has_many :timeslots, :through => :availabilities
end

# models/availability.rb
# projects table should have these columns - user_id:integer, timeslot_id:integer
class Availability < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :timeslot
  belongs_to :user
end    

# models/timeslot.rb
class Timeslot < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :availabilities
  has_many :users, :through => :availabilities
end
```

You need a migration to create `availabilities` table which acts as a join table for your has_many through relationship between `Timeslot` Object and `User` Object. Migration file looks something like this:

```
class CreateAvailabilities < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :availabilities do |t|
      t.integer :user_id
      t.integer :timeslot_id
    end
  end
end
```

**Access**

`User.last.timeslots` gives 0, 1 or many timeslots associated with `User.last`

`Timeslot.last.users` gives 0, 1 or many users associated with `Timeslot.last`